# How to import category and sub category programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I am searching tutorials for importing categories and subcategories in Magento 2. Can anyone please explain in which path this code is to be written?

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

/// Get Website ID
$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
echo 'websiteId: '.$websiteId." ";

/// Get Store ID
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
echo 'storeId: '.$storeId." ";

/// Get Root Category ID
$rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
echo 'rootNodeId: '.$rootNodeId." ";

/// Get Root Category
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootNodeId);

$categorys=array('Levis','Wranglers','Basics'); // Category Names
foreach($categorys as $cat)
{
    $name=ucfirst($cat);
    $url=strtolower($cat);
    $cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
    $categoryFactory=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    /// Add a new sub category under root category
    $categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();
    $categoryTmp->setName($name);
    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);
    $categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
    $categoryTmp->setParentId($rootCat->getId());
    $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
    $categoryTmp->setImage('/m2.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/m2.png
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
    $categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
    $categoryTmp->save();
}
```

Comment: Maha use some extension to import & export your categories

Comment: I'm using like .../Catalog/Setup  and also Magento2/app/.but not working

Comment: you can use in root directory by saving as a php file